# What does systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2 mean in ldap?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

When I write the following ldap query in C#:

> (&(objectClass=crossRef)(**systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2**))

What exactly the `systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2` filter is used for?

I'm trying to follow the following MSDN explanation but yet I don't understand :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223141.aspx

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Extensible Match matching rule where 1.2.840.113556.1.4.803
AKA [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/1.2.840.113556.1.4.803) is checking that the bit "2" is set.

In your particular use with systemFlags, is implies ["When applied to an attribute, the attribute will be replicated to the global catalog. When applied to a Cross-Ref object, the naming context is a domain."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680022(v=vs.85).aspx)

-jim